# Send download link after Bitcoin payment

Tags: download, bitcoin, marketplace

I'm starting an online business.
My website is hosted on OVH.
I would like to send a download link after a bitcoin payment.

- Are there specific stuffs I should be aware of?
- Is this difficult to develop? (I have a bit of experience with JS, JAVA HTML/CSS)
- Is it safe to store the file directly on my FTP?
- Do external websites already provide this kind of services?
- What could be the best language to use with the blockchain api?

Just to be more specific:

The scheme of the whole think would be:

- user: I'm interested in your product
- server: Please pay for it with your bitcoins
- user: ok I'll do that I'll go on your dedicated page
- server: Ok we received your payment you just received a link for you to download our file.
- user: thanks it works!

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: this might be better suited to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com - some q/a there refer to services with APIs you can use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

• You should be aware of all the security issues around Bitcoin, if you're receiving funds to your own bitcoin wallet you need to keep that secure and if you're using a service you need to make sure you don't rely on it too heavily or keep too many funds in it's hands

• It is difficult to develop on your own as you should really have an offline wallet for the BTC. If you just create a php script loaded with 100 Bitcoin addresses you can get by with a small store and no Bitcoin-specific code.

• Is it safe to store the file directly on FTP? Yes… also if it's not protected the link could be shared.

• http://coinbase.com are probably the leading provider of this service

• blockchain.info provides official API libraries for Python, Java, .NET (C#), Tuby, PHP and Node - so whichever of those you know best.